Can't install QGIS 3.40 on D drive
I am trying to install QGIS 3.40 on my D drive. Even though I select the D drive as the destination, the setup is not working because it says:

"Out of Disk Space - Disk space required for the installation exceeds
available disk space."

It goes on to say:

"The highlighted volumes do not have enough disk space available for
the currently selected features. You can remove some files from the
highlighted volumes, install fewer features, or select a different
destination drive."

C drive is highlighted in the list of volumes, even though I selected the D drive in the previous step. I can't change the highlighted volume in this step!
I want the program on my D drive because I have more space there. There is not enough space on my C drive.

are you using the msi installer on c drive or d drive? and how much space on each? 3.40 RC is 2.9GB

Maybe some space is needed on C: for storing temporary files during installation.

See https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/58187.
